# Install new version of C-ares on Centos 7

Tags: centos, php

I'm trying to install a more recent version of [c-ares](https://c-ares.org/) on a Centos 7 server. The repo only has 1.10.

Any ideas other than upgrading to Centos 8 to get c-ares 1.13 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best option is probably to download the source rpm for c-ares 1.13 from the Centos 8 repo and recompile it for Centos 7, then install the new package.  In other words, backport it.

Note that while the library's major version hasn't changed and that custom dictates that the major version **should** be changed when there are incompatible changes, that doesn't always happen.   So, while installing the updated version **shouldn't** cause any breakage, that's not guaranteed.  Keep an eye on it, and be ready to downgrade to the older version if the upgrade causes other programs to break.

It's also worth noting that sometimes backporting one package will also require backporting other packages that it depends upon (or packages that depend upon it)....and that those packages may, in turn, require other packages to be backported.  If there are only a small number of easily backported packages to do, that can be worth the effort.  For long and complex dependency chains, you'd be much better off just upgrading to Centos 8.

---

BTW, do you actually **need** version 1.13?  Are there essential bug-fixes or improvements that you known you need, or do you just **want** the new version because it's newer and you believe that "newer = better"?

Remember that while new versions often come with fixes to existing bugs, they sometimes come with exciting new bugs too.

Comment: BTW, according to the c-ares.org website, 1.10 was released in May 2013.  1.13 is from June 2017.  The latest version is 1.18.1 from Oct 27 2021.    If you want the latest, shiniest, newest version make a package of 1.18.1 from the upstream source.  You may be able to re-use/edit the spec file from the 1.10 or 1.13 version, or you might have to start the packaging process from scratch.   the library .so version for 1.18.1 is now libcares.so.2 so anything that uses it would have to be recompiled against the new library headers.